# How to create hyperlinks that link to files in different folder locations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column in excel with the names of different invoices on my computer and I need to create a hyperlink for each invoice name. I tried to press CTRL+K and manually create a hyperlink for each invoice at the beginning, but that was just too much work because I have hundreds of invoices.

Right now, I am using this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\2015\January" & B2 & ".xlsx", B2)
```

and it is working fine. However, not every invoice is in this folder so, I need a formula that looks up the file from the external folder.

[image: The excel sheet looks something like this]

Comment: For starters, I would probably grab the year (e.g. `YEAR(A2)` ) as part of the folder path string construction.

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula. This should work for you creating dynamic hyperlinks for each month and year.

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\"& TEXT(A2,"yyyy") &"\" & TEXT(A2,"mmmm") & B2 & ".xlsx", B2)
```

Comment: I was trying your formula earlier, but Excel found a "typo" and tried to correct it by removing the equal sign in: "& =TEXT(A2,"mmmm") & B2 & ".xlsx", B2)". I clicked "Yes," and it said "Cannot open the specified file." I clicked "No," and Excel said "We found a problem with this formula." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place the cursor on the cell where you have pasted this formula. Just hover over the cell, do not click it. Now, Excel will display the actual hyper link. Verify whether the link is correctly converted to a actual path in your computer.

Comment: The path is incorrect. It shows "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\2015\January000000.xlsx", so I need another backslash (\) between "January" and "000000". I tried "=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\"& TEXT(A2,"yyyy") &"\" & TEXT(A2,"mmmm") &"\" & B2  & ".xlsx", B2)" and it now works perfectly. Fantastic.