# How to retrieve cell value from different workbooks in various file paths?

Tags: vba, excel

The columns in question are D, E, F, G, and H, and I want them to retrieve values from cells in other workbooks in different file locations.

Each of the aforementioned columns in Index.xlsx corresponds to certain cells in the invoice workbooks that I have (e.g. 000000.xlsx, 000006.xlsx, and 000011.xlsx).

However, not all of the invoices are located in the same folder. For example, **000000.xlsx** is in "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\2015\January" and **000007.xlsx** is in "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\2015\March"

For clarification, this is what I want them to do.

- **D2** in Index.xlsx *retrieves value from* **B1** in 000000.xlsx
- **E2** in Index.xlsx *retrieves value from* **B5** in
    000000.xlsx
- **F2** in Index.xlsx *retrieves value from* **B6** in 000000.xlsx
- **G2** in Index.xlsx *retrieves value from* **B7** in 000000.xlsx
- **H2** in Index.xlsx *retrieves value from* **B9** in
    000000.xlsx

[image]

*I have hundreds of invoices so I cannot type them manually, and so I will need a formula that does this automatically. However, is it possible to make a formula for this without using VBA (I have no knowledge of it)?

** The third column was created based on the formula in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701226/how-to-create-hyperlinks-that-link-to-files-in-different-folder-locations) thread.

Comment: This Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059343/excel-formula-how-to-concatenate-string-for-external-reference will help you achieve your goal. Use file names in column B.

Comment: I should clarify that not all of the invoices are located in the same folder, so this method doesn't work for all of the files I have.

Comment: You can use ExecuteExcel4Macro to get the values of the cells, but then they won't update automatically, if the value in the referenced cell changes.

Answer (score 2):

This code should do the trick.

```
Sub test()

Dim ChkRng As Range, ws As Worksheet, strPath As String, strMonth As String, cell As Range, strSheet As String, strYear As String, strFormula as string

Set ws = ActiveSheet

strPath = "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Excel Formula Testing\"

With ws
    Set ChkRng = .Range("A2", Range("A" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
End With

For Each cell In ChkRng
    strYear = Right(cell.Value, 4) & "\"
    strMonth = Left(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") - 1) & "\"
    strFile = cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & ".xlsx"
    strSheet = "Sheet1"
    strFormula = "='" & strPath & strYear & strMonth & "[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet
    cell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = strFormula & "'!B1"
    cell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = strFormula & "'!B5"
    cell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = strFormula & "'!B6"
    cell.Offset(0, 6).Formula = strFormula & "'!B7"
    cell.Offset(0, 7).Formula = strFormula & "'!B9"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Change the static strings according to your needs, and it should work, if the folder and file exists.
Atleast it did for me in my small made up example.

ps. Remember to change strSheet to whatever the name of the sheet in the invoice files is, and if it's a static sheet name, move it up under strPath, or atleast over the For Each .... Next Loop.

If it doesn't work, comment, and I'll see what I can do.